# c# nested transaction with sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

When I update sth to MS SQL 2005 database with c#, I want to use a nested sql transaction. I have tried the following code:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

    ////BEGIN TRAN
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "storeprocname";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@xxx", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters["@xxx"].Value = "string_value";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (<sql can do>)
    {
        cmd.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
}
```

The above code open a transaction and put some data in sql. It can Sussessfully run if the data I put is correct. But if it isn't, it catched the following error which is totally different than I expected, which is :

> [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"Cannot roll back updatetransport. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.\r\nTransaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 1, current count = 2."}

and the code is sql:

```
begin tran updatetransport
update db set xxx=@xxx  where xxx=@xxx
if @@rowcount < 1 or @@error <> 0 -- no record updated  
begin
    rollback tran updatetransport /*updatran is the name of transaction*/
 return -1 --fail
    end  
   else
begin  
 commit tran updatetransport
 return 0 --success  
end
```

It appeared that the sql server is automatically rollback the transaction. And throw out error when I tried to rollback it. However when I tried to modify the code in following way, there is still no luck. Do I miss out anything?
I have declare `@tcount =@@TRANCOUNT` just after begin transaction.

```
 if @tcount = @@TRANCOUNT
 begin
    rollback tran updatetransport
 end
```

Comment: Avoid nested transactions. Because they aren't. I've been coding for quite a while and never needed a nested transaction in code. The fact you think you need one suggests your design may be wrong.

Comment: You already have a transaction in your stored procedure, you don't need another one in the c# code.

Comment: I understand that this is redundant, but sometimes there may be two people handling sql and c#. Also this is so frustrating where some idea logically works, but it happens not as expected. Right or wrong it has to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

You should not start nested transaction if already exist outer, for this you could check @@trancount variable in begin procedure and in the end:

```
declare @trancount int = @@trancount

if @trancount = 0 
  begin tran updatetransport

update db set xxx=@xxx  where xxx=@xxx
if @@rowcount < 1 or @@error <> 0 -- no record updated  
begin
    if @trancount = 0 
      rollback tran updatetransport /*updatran is the name of transaction*/
 return -1 --fail
    end  
   else
begin  
  if @trancount = 0 
   commit tran updatetransport
 return 0 --success  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't really have nested transactions -- or at least in a way that a developer would assume. You can start nested transactions, but they don't really have any affect because committing the innermost transaction doesn't do anything in reality.

You cannot rollback the innermost transaction at all, since it's not possible to use the names with rollback, and rollback without the name does a rollback for the outermost transaction.

You can find examples in this blog post by [Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)